# Antivirus for file upload in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, file-upload, server

What is the best way to virus scan the uploaded files in my node js express project.
I'm having a csv file upload functionality in my project. It's recommended to do a virus scan of the files uploaded. I'm using multer for upload

Comment: Do you really need to scan a csv file? I mean this is a text file, you will not open it in any executable way and surely will never run it. How much sense does the virus scan make?

Answer (score 1):

You shall use Virustotal which will give you API access for uploading file after analyzing its result you can decide to accept uploaded file or not.

Reference:
https://developers.virustotal.com/reference